# Change font for 'Author', RMarkdown

Tags: html, css, fonts, r-markdown

I would like to modify the default font size and color of the 'Author' and 'Date' of a Rmd document. I looked up and tried modifying it using a CSS stylesheet. The font of the 'Title' got modified but I cannot modify the 'Author' and 'Date'. Here is what I tried so far for 'Author'.

```
<style type="text/css">
body{ /* Normal  */
  font-size: 14px;
}
h1.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: DarkRed;
}
h2.author {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: DarkBlue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It is `<h4 class="author">`.

Comment: Many thanks!! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The author and date headers specified in the YAML are h4 by default. The below works:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{ /* Normal  */
  font-size: 14px;
}
h1.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: DarkRed;
}
h4.author {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: DarkBlue;
}
</style>
```